# Concatenate multiple node values in xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery, spring-el

I have a XML that looks like this

```
<element1>
    <element2>
        <element3>    
            <element4>Hello</element4>
            <element5>World</element5>
        </element3>
        <element3>    
            <element4>Hello2</element4>
            <element5>World2</element5>
        </element3>
        <element3>    
            <element4>Hello3</element4>
            <element5>World3</element5>
        </element3>
    </element2>
</element1>
```

I am trying to use Xpath to get a result like this:

```
Hello.World
Hello2.World2
Hello3.World3
```

I used concat function below but I did not get correct result.

Concat function:

```
concat(/element1/element2/element3/element4/text(),".", /element1/element2/element3/element5/text())
```

Result I got:

```
Hello.World
```

How can I get the correct result?
I am using XPath with Camel Spring DSL.

**Edit:**

Solutions in XQuery, XSLT and SPel are also appreciated.

**Edit**

I tried string-join and it did not work:

string-join function:

```
string-join((/element1/element2/element3/element4/text(), /element1/element2/element3/element5/text()),".")
```

Result I got:

```
Hello.Hello2.Hello3.World.World2.World3
```

Comment: In XPath2.0 there is `string-join`, looks more appropriate there.. However, what is with XSLT? I would use that here.

Comment: Added edit for string-join function. Also added XSLT to tags and requested solution.

Comment: To understand why you get this result: A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this expression...

```
string-join(//element3/(concat(element4/text(), '.', element5/text())), "&#10;")
```

Comment: If you want a Sequence of results, the more succinct way is to use `//element3/string-join(element4 | element5, ".")`, and if you must have a single string as a result then, `string-join(//element3/string-join(element4 | element5, "."), "&#xa;")` is another formulation, which IMHO is more readable.

Comment: +1 for the `//el/string-join(el2 | el3, 'separator')`. I used this to scrape images and generate a CSV: `//img/string-join(@src | @alt | @width | @height, '|')`

Comment: Be careful with `//element3/string-join(element4 | element5, ".")`. Regardless of the order you give `element4` and `element5`, the union operator `|` will maintain _document order_! That means `//element3/string-join(element5 | element4, ".")` will produce the same result as `//element3/string-join(element4 | element5, ".")` for the same input document. I usually want to control the order, so I prefer to simply list the items using the form `//element3/string-join((element4, element5), ".")`.

Answer (score 23):

I used concat method and works well.

```
concat(//SomeElement/text(),'_',//OtherElement/text())
```

Answer (score 16):

Here comes a solution with `XSLT`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//element3">
    <xsl:value-of select="element4/text()" />.<xsl:value-of select="element5/text()" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What's the point of down-voting this? Note that `string-join()` is available only for XPath2.0. That's why I suggested to use XSLT

Answer (score 2):

Using `XQuery`:

`for $d in $doc/element2/element3 return fn:string-join(fn:data($d/element()), ".")`.
$doc stores the Xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to join xpath-selected text nodes but can not use `string-join` (when you are stuck with XSL 1.0) this might help:

```
<xsl:variable name="x">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="..." mode="string-join-mode"/>
</xsl:variable>
joined and normalized: <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($x)"/>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="string-join-mode">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="string-join-mode"/>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="string-join-mode">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:template match="element3">
        <xsl:value-of select="element4,element5" separator="."/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Just posting code is not a good answer. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) if you haven't read it.