# Using XPath is it possible to get the name of each node in a path to a target node as a String?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

**Using XPath is it possible to get the name of each node in a path to a target node as a String?**

*Example.xml*

```
<parent>
    <childOne>
        <target>true</target>
    </childOne>

    <childTwo>
        <target>true</target>
    </childTwo>

    <childThree>
        <target>false</target>
    </childThree>
</parent>
```

*Selects all ancestors where target is true*

`//node()[target = "true"]/ancestor-or-self::*`

*Is it possible to get this result*

`"parent/childOne/target"`

`"parent/childTwo/target"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this XPath 2.0 expression:

```
string-join(for $node in //node()[text() = 'true'] return string-join(for $ancestor in $node/ancestor-or-self::* return concat('/',local-name($ancestor)), ''), '&#10;')
```

This will return the path strings seperated by newline characters. If you want seperate result nodes for each path you may want to use

```
for $node in //node()[text() = 'true'] return string-join(for $ancestor in $node/ancestor-or-self::* return concat('/',local-name($ancestor)), '')
```

instead.

Note that I had to change `target = 'true'` into `text() = 'true'` to include the tags at the lowest level.

The trick with the concatenation of the partial path strings was inspired by this answer: [Concatenate multiple node values in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996965/concatenate-multiple-node-values-in-xpath)