# How to retrieve two attributes for each required node

Tags: xpath

I am using Google Sheet to read XML data.
Unfortunately I am struggling to extract the XML correctly.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp, SO and other Googled sources didn't help.

While processing the simplified data below

```
<item>
    <profile_url>www.profile1.com</profile_url>
    <answers>
        <answers_item>
            <answer>answer text 1.1</answer>
        </answers_item>
        <answers_item>
            <answer>answer text 1.2</answer>
        </answers_item>
    </answers>
<item>
<item>
    <profile_url>www.profile2.com</profile_url>
    <answers>
        <answers_item>
            <answer>answer text 2.1</answer>
        </answers_item>
        <answers_item>
            <answer>answer text 2.2</answer>
        </answers_item>
    </answers>
<item>
```

The output needs to be in the following format so additional formatting isn't required in a spreadsheet

```
www.profile1.com   answer text 1.1   answer text 1.2
www.profile2.com   answer text 2.1   answer text 2.2
```

Variants tried and failed to give the correct output are

```
"//profile_url //answers/answers_item/answer"
"//profile_url | //answers/answers_item/answer"
```

Thanks in advance
Rob

---

Tried fixes from [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996965%20identified%20duplicate)

1) Using string-join

```
string-join(//item/(concat(profile_url/text(), '.', answers/answers_item/answer//text())), "&#10;")
```

Gave the follow error (maybe because XPath used is not 2.0)

```
Imported Xml content can not be parsed.
```

2) Using

```
concat(//profile_url/text(), " ", //answers/answers_item/answer/text())
```

Gave the first entry only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate multiple node values in xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996965/concatenate-multiple-node-values-in-xpath)

Comment: Added failed results of suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only two `answers_item`s in each `item`, the following xpath

`concat(//item[1]/profile_url, " ", //item[1]/answers/answers_item[1]/answer, " " , //item[1]/answers/answers_item[2]/answer)`

should give the required output as :

`www.profile1.com   answer text 1.1   answer text 1.2`  for the first `item`

For the second one, you need to modify `item[1]` to `item[2]`

This can be easily done if you are working in Java.

Comment: Thanks, but there are 6,000 records to process and the output goes to a spreadsheet - so no Java present.So the iteration needs to happen within the XPath statement.

Comment: When you say "no java" do you mean this is all taking place on the web page itself?  If so, sounds like you need to use Javascript or VBScript to accomplish what you want here.  What is it using to "get the data to the spreadsheet" now?

Comment: @RobertSharpe `iteration needs to happen within the XPath statement.` ? It is not possible for your requirement. You cannot use `concat` to print all nodes. You can get the nodes themselves but not the text in them concatenated in the format you want. BTW how are you evaluating your XPath expressions ? Which engine?

Comment: @Bil-Hilerman As the first sentence says "I am using Google Sheet to read XML data."  It is happening in a Google Sheet using the IMPORTXML function (see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) that takes an  XPath parameter to specify the fields from the read XML data.

Comment: @svasa cancat was just an example someone else suggested.  The XPath expressions are being evaluated by the IMPORTXML function.

I am sure that a powerful language like XPath can format more than 1 parameter in an easy to import way - it is just knowing the correct command.