# How to get selected text between different tags with XPath?

Tags: xpath

I try to get text values from between `span` tags with XPath which do not contain a class attribute with the value "hide". Please show me the right way, based on my example code. My code is only a part of a large HTML code.

I tried with this:

```
//div[@class='nr']//span[contains(@class,'hide')]
```

...which is get the `span`s which have class "hide", but I can't able to negate the selection. I tried on many way but without success.

```
<div class="nr" x-ms-format-detection="none">
    <i class="icon icon_phone">Tel.</i>
    <span class="nr">
        <span>
            <span class="hide"> 7</span>
            0
            <span class="hide"> 3</span>
            1
            <span class="hide"> 62</span>
            7
            <span class="hide"> 129</span>
            9
            <span class="hide"> 3</span>        
            <span class="hide">&nbsp;</span>
            2
            <span class="hide"> 279</span>
            <span class="hide"> 061</span>
            9
            <span class="hide"> 91</span>
            0
            <span class="hide"> 764</span>
            <span class="hide"> 2</span>
            5
            <span class="hide">&nbsp;</span>
            9
            <span class="hide"> 018</span>
            <span class="hide">&nbsp;</span>
            9
            <span class="hide"> 16</span>
            9
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

The expected result looks like:
01792905999

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate multiple node values in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996965/concatenate-multiple-node-values-in-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with XPath-2.0.
And an approach is to select all `text()` nodes that are children of a certain `<span>` node:

```
string-join(//div[@class='nr']/span[@class='nr']/span/text()/normalize-space())
```

Comment: My question is about HOW distinguish values and not how to concatenate. Your answer will produce a wrong result: 703162712993227906199107640590189169
The expected result need to be a string: 01792905999 (without the `<span class="hide">` values) OR an array of numbers in right sequence.

Comment: @LisaWarner: I double-checked my code with Saxon XSLT and the returned value is correct and as desired. But I do not know what XSLT processor you do use.