# How to correctly concatenate XPath?

Tags: xpath, concatenation, string-concatenation, xpath-1.0

I try to match multiple elements and all their occurences through concatenation.

I tried two expressions

```
concat(//h5,'###',//h5/following-sibling::p)
concat(//*/h5,'###',//*/h5/following-sibling::p)
```

but both work partly - they match only the first occurence.

What I'm doing wrong? What is the working way to match all occurences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate multiple node values in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996965/concatenate-multiple-node-values-in-xpath)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen , no. I used already, and notified in my post, all variants from the thread you link. Non-used variants are from other XPath version as I have, and notified in my post.

Answer (score 1):

The `string([node-set])` function is - most probably - implicitly used when the argument is an expression like `//*/h5` so

`contact(//*/h5, "some")`
could translate to
`concat(string(//*/h5), "some")`.

From [string() doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/string):

> If the object is a **node-set**, the string value of the **first node** in the set is returned.

To answer OP's question

> What I'm doing wrong? What is the working way to match all occurences?

Nothing wrong per se, it's just many XPath 1.0 function operate only on the first element of a node set.

Those node sets should be iterated externally.